# Flying EU to UK to EU. Can I get duty free alcohol?

Tags: uk, alcohol, taxes, brexit

On the 20 of March this year I will be flying from Ireland to the UK and then on the another EU country.

Can I buy duty free alcohol (as in alcohol with no tax) leaving the UK ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, the UK is in the transition period of brexit where nothing has changed in that regard. This is currently due to end on 31st December 2020.